# Binary search inside sorted array in OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, ocaml-batteries

```
let find arr word =
  let rec binaryserach arr word min max =
    let mid = (min + max) / 2 in
    if max < min then -1 else
    if (String.compare arr.(mid)  word = 0) then mid else 
    if (String.compare arr.(mid)  word = 1) then (binaryserach arr word (mid+1) max) else
      binaryserach arr word min (mid-1) in 
  binaryserach arr word 0 ((Array.length arr) - 1) ;;
```

I am trying to do binary serach in OCaml. What is wrong in this code? It always return -1. It is an array of strings so that comparing elements gives values 0,-1 or 1 if they are equal, first element lesser and first element greater respectively(Documentation says positive and negative integers but I have tested in interpreter and recieved 1 and -1). Any hint about the mistake I have made here?

Comment: Its giving the same results when using =,<,and > instead of String.compare. So problem is something else

Comment: can you add the calling code?

Comment: `find [|"a"; "b"; "c"|] "a"` returns -1 @Grozz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this `if (String.compare arr.(mid)  word = 1)`  to `-1`.

`String.compare` returns `1` if left side is greater than right.

**Note:** the general approach taken contains minor known error described in wikipedia article here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Implementation_issues

Basically, calculating `mid` as `(min + max) / 2` gives an integer overflow for large enough numbers.